# Windows 7 and wireless N, how do I choose which frequency to connect to?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking, 802.11n

I have a dual band wireless N router broadcasting on both frequencies with the same SSID. When I attempt to connect to the wireless, it seems to pick at random if it connects to the 2.4 or 5GHz frequency, causing me to have to guess at which wireless key to use.

If I set one of the frequencies as open, I can see both frequencies in windows 7, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: Can you change the SSID on one and not the other?  That would simplify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you can't do this.  If the profile is the same from an ssid and encryption perspective, they are seen as equal options.

I keep the SSIDs different for different freqencies precisely for this reason, it enables you to set preferences in OS over which frequency band is chosen.

Comment: "I am pretty sure you can't do this" - He can, and he did, and it's the root cause of his dilemma.  Replace "can't" with "shouldn't", and then this answer makes more sense.  BTW I also have unique SSIDs for each band.

Comment: @sawdust You misunderstand what I am referring to.  He is asking whether he can select between two networks that have the same ssid and encryption under windows 7, that differ only by the frequency band they use.  I am pretty sure you cannot.